# In React + Django app, JS renders properly when TS doesn't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, typescript

I know JS and React, but have zero experience with TS.
I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JD-age0BPVo) on YT, but figured I'd use TS to learn it, instead of JS.

And so after some setting up, I figured I'm ready to continue with the tutorial. However...

This works with JS:

index.html (Django template):

```
[irrelevant html setup]
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="app"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
</body>
```

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  return <h1>Testing React code</h1>;
};

export default App;

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

index.js:

```
import App from "./components/App";
// that's it. The import is all there is in index.js
```

This is later compiled by babel-loader to main.js, which I'll not paste here, since it unreadable anyway. However, it does render the text from App.js.

When I have the analogical setup with TS, it doesn't work for some reason.

App.tsx:

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

const App: FC = () => {
  return <h1>Testing React code</h1>;
};

export default App;

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

index.ts is the same as index.js, html file also remains unchanged.

I run `tsc` compiler, then `run dev` script that uses babel-loader. File main.js is created, but it has a one long line, and nothing is rendered when I run server.
Files App.js and index.js are created during compilation, but index.js has just `export {}` in it.

I suppose this is due to a difference in how TS and JS work, but I'm not sure what to even look for. I get no error messages.

Comment: There seems to be no mention of any `.ts` files in the project. Do you have any typescript files at all? If so, could you share the code in those

Comment: @HassanNaqvi I edited the post to show some .ts and .tsx code, but it's basically the same code on a different git branch.